# R plotly line chart

Tags: r, plotly

I have a data set with three variables namely Gender, Age and BMI and this is the sample of data:

[image]

I am trying to plot line chart in r using plotly package, where X axis shows BMI values, Y axis shows Age and Gender plot two lines as a values corresponding to BMI and Age. I am trying these code but could not got proper output.

Here is my code:

```
    library(plotly)
data<-read.csv("abc1.csv")
p <- plot_ly(data, x = ~BMI, y = ~Age, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',
             linetype = ~Gender,line = list(color = 'rgb(205, 12, 24)', width = 4)) %>%
  layout(title = "Line chart",
         xaxis = list(title = "Age"),
         yaxis = list (title = "BMI"))
p
```

Here is my console output:

[image]

Comment: Try running dput(data) and copy/paste what you get in your console into your question. That way we can work with your actual data.

Comment: I tried with dput() function but could not get proper output

Comment: I've recreated your data set below as `df` in my answer. If this is what is in your CSV, you would basically use the command `dput(df)` and then copy and paste the "structure" that R prints out after.

Answer (score 0):

### Recreating data frame:

First, I tried to recreate your data below:

```
Gender <- c("M",
            "F",
            "F",
            "M",
            "M",
            "F",
            "M",
            "M",
            "M",
            "F",
            "F",
            "M",
            "M")
Age <- c(75.6,
         81.9,
         81.9,
         83.2,
         84.6,
         84.9,
         88,
         89.1,
         90.1,
         90.4,
         92.9,
         93,
         93.4)
BMI <- c(16.2,
         17.3,
         14.9,
         19.6,
         15.5,
         14.7,
         15,
         14.8,
         19.2,
         16.4,
         16.1,
         15.7,
         25.2)
df <- data.frame(Gender,
                 Age,
                 BMI)
df
```

Which gives us this:

```
   Gender  Age  BMI
1       M 75.6 16.2
2       F 81.9 17.3
3       F 81.9 14.9
4       M 83.2 19.6
5       M 84.6 15.5
6       F 84.9 14.7
7       M 88.0 15.0
8       M 89.1 14.8
9       M 90.1 19.2
10      F 90.4 16.4
11      F 92.9 16.1
12      M 93.0 15.7
13      M 93.4 25.2
```

### Creating the plot (plotly method)

What is probably wrong here is the way you have faceted your data. I have edited your code like this:

```
library(plotly)
p <- plot_ly(df, 
             x = ~Age, 
             y = ~BMI,
             type = 'scatter', 
             mode = 'lines',
             color = ~Gender) %>% 
  layout(title = "Line chart",
         xaxis = list(title = "Age"),
         yaxis = list (title = "BMI"))
p
```

Which facets the data correctly here:

[image]

If you are dead set on adding line types per gender, you can also just do the same thing for line type:

```
p <- plot_ly(df, 
             x = ~Age, 
             y = ~BMI,
             type = 'scatter', 
             mode = 'lines',
             color = ~Gender,
             linetype = ~Gender) %>% 
  layout(title = "Line chart",
         xaxis = list(title = "Age"),
         yaxis = list (title = "BMI"))
```

Which makes this:

[image]

### Creating the plot (ggpubr method)

One way you could do it is by porting a ggpubr or ggplot line graph into the `ggplotly` function which serves the same function. I used my own palette for the colors, but you can select whatever color you want with RGB codes:

```
library(ggpubr)
line <- ggline(df,
       x="Age",
       y="BMI",
       color = "Gender",
       palette = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"),
       title = "Line Graph")
ggplotly(line)
```

Which makes this plotly line graph:

[image]

Again, not sure from your code what you were trying to do, but you can also make a red and dashed type line with this method:

```
line <- ggline(df,
       x="Age",
       y="BMI",
       linetype = "Gender",
       color = "red",
       title = "Line Graph")
ggplotly(line)
```

Which makes this:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Hope you are looking for best-fit line graph

```r
#sample data
df <- data.frame(Age=c(75.6, 81.9, 81.9,83.2,84.6,84.9,88,89.1),
                 Gender=c('M','F','F','M','M','F','M','M'),
                 BMI=c(16.2,17.3,14.9,19.6,15.5,14.7,15,14.8))

gender <- levels(df$Gender)
col <- c('red','green','blue')

library(plotly)
p <- plot_ly()
for (i in 1:length(gender)) {
  p <- p %>%
    add_lines(data = df[df$Gender==gender[i],],
              x = ~BMI,
              y = fitted(lm(data = df[df$Gender==gender[i],], Age ~ BMI)),
              line = list(color = col[i]),
              name = gender[i]) %>%
    add_markers(data = df[df$Gender==gender[i],], 
                x = ~BMI,
                y = ~Age,
                symbol = ~Gender,
                marker=list(color = col[i]))
}
p %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(title = "BMI"), yaxis = list(title = "Age"), title="BMI-Age Line Chart")
```